# with drf-yasg, how to supply patterns?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger

I have installed drf-yasg, and it's working great. The problem I've got is that it's a big app, and has a huge amount of endpoints for each type of frontend client, i.e. `/admin/v1`, `/app/v1`, ...

So I thought it would be a good idea to separate documentation for each type, i.e

```
urlpatterns += [
     url(r'^/admin/swagger/$', admin_schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
     url(r'^/app/swagger/$', app_schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
]
```

So it looks as though drf-yasg supports this, via supplying `patterns` into the `get_scheme_view`:

```
admin_schema_view = get_schema_view(
    openapi.Info(
        title="API",
        default_version='v1',
        description="The set of API endpoints used.",
        terms_of_service="https://www.google.com/policies/terms/",
        contact=openapi.Contact(email="contact@me"),
        license=openapi.License(name="BSD License"),
    ),
    patterns=?????,
    validators=['flex', 'ssv'],
    public=True,
    permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),
)
```

Now my guess was to supply a string, the same way as the first string when defining `urls`, such as `patterns=r'^admin/v1/',` which results in:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- packages/rest_framework/compat.py", line 55, in get_original_route
return urlpattern.regex.pattern
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'regex'
```

So with the documentation at [drf-yasg docs](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/drf-yasg/latest/drf-yasg.pdf#page=57&zoom=100,0,200):

> patterns – if given, only these patterns will be enumerated for inclusion in the API spec

Exactly what type of object is needed here in order for to process `patterns`? I've tried looking around the django-rest-framework and Django source code on github, but couldn't find what type is actually needed, they are both very large projects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some experiments I found out the patterns it is expecting is a list of url patterns and not just a standard Python regex string. It should exactly be the same standard django `urlpatterns` in `urls.py`.

So assuming you have imported your admin API url patterns as `admin_urlpatterns`, all you need is specify it in the patterns option

```
admin_schema_view = get_schema_view(
openapi.Info(
    title="API",
    default_version='v1',
    description="The set of API endpoints used.",
    terms_of_service="https://www.google.com/policies/terms/",
    contact=openapi.Contact(email="contact@me"),
    license=openapi.License(name="BSD License"),
),
patterns=admin_urlpatterns,
validators=['flex', 'ssv'],
public=True,
permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),
)
```

It was definitely difficult to find any example and they may want to include a vivid example in the docs

Comment: How embarrassing I didn't think to do that, must have been too tired to think properly, thanks a lot!

Comment: @jupiar it's totally normal. It wasn't so obvious to me at first too :)

Comment: I followed your answer, and it works in the sense that it looks fine in the front end but when I execute the requests they fail because the build urls are incorrect. I introduce something like: `patterns=[path(f'api/poll/', include(f"api_poll.urls", namespace=f'api_poll'))]`. It shows the right endpoints, but when I try to execute things in the swagger, it adds an extra `poll` in the url, so, instead of `http://host.com/api/poll/...` it shows `http://host.com/api/poll/poll/...`.

Comment: I basically patch the error by modifying the `get_paths()` in my `CustomSchemaGenerator` that inherits from [`OpenAPISchemaGenerator`](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/blob/0991c806c7d452524a4350db02877ba2a0202198/src/drf_yasg/generators.py#L379-L414). I basically, hardcoded the desired prefixed `api/poll` instead of `api/poll/poll`. This patch would do for now, but I would like to fix this properly.

Comment: I also figure out that if you send the router (`rest_framework.routers.DefaultRouter`) as a parameter in patterns (i.e. `patterns=self.router.get_urls(),`) the front end will also be displayed correctly. The patch in the `CustomSchemaGenerator` is still needed.

Comment: @toto_tico Are you sure it is not connected with the F-strings you're using? I see no need using it there since there are no parameters needed. It worked perfectly when I tried it without any further modifications

Comment: @Ken4scholars, I just put the f-strings to simplify my example. I do actually need the f-string in my real application, as it is much more complex that this. I have programmed an API pattern Django App that can be reused by other Apps to quickly set up a default API, so I have something like f'api/{appname}'.  In any case, the f-string must be evaluated immediately to literals (I have been using them for more than a year and I have never seen any problems with them).

Comment: @toto_tico maybe it's not the F-strings but something else specific with your custom configuration. As I said, it worked for me and seems to have worked for the OP too

Comment: So, In my project `urls.py`, I had this `urlpatterns=[path('api/', include("app1.urls")),  path('api/', include("app2.urls"))...]`, so that `path('api/'` appears twice. Then, in each app, I would make the dissambiguation: for app1: `urlpatterns = [path(r'^app1/', include(router.urls)), ...`, and for app2: `urlpatterns = [path(r'^app2/', include(router.urls)), ...`. This seems to confuse the `drf_yasg`. Instead, The disambiguation must happen in the project `urls.py`: `urlpatterns= [ ... path('api/app1', include("app1.urls")),  path('api/app2', include("app2.urls"))]`.

Comment: I would preffer my initial approach because I want to create some generic code fora an api app, I don't see why would it be wrong. Nevertheless, drf_yasg seem to only understand when the dissambiguation of the names is done as the project `urls.py` level.